# How can I prevent Facebook from loading preview images of my Blogger posts?

Tags: facebook, blogger

Whenever I post a link to my blog at blogspot.com on Facebook, a wrong or completely irrelevant thumbnail image is loaded. Is there a way to prevent Facebook from loading any image from my blog at all? Perhaps some HTML or CSS code I could use on Blogger?

Comment: Add metatags to your page to tell Facebook which image to use.

Comment: Here is the code I use.  https://gist.github.com/nalexiou-loc/b6121aabec2c18f88cd9fdbdf3d3122f

Comment: Thanks Nikos, but that didn't work unfortunately. I pasted it below the <head> tag and no effect.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your blog structure invalid, such as og image... cause, normally... facebook or another social media get data image from post..

**first image..**

*if you want to show relevant image.. just put it first on your post*

check your page structure using google page structure tool from webmaster.